# Angular Js Custom Directive is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive like below.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('directive.test', [])
    .directive('test', test);
  test.$inject = [];
/* @ngInject */
  function test() {
    // Usage:
    //
    // Creates:
    //
    var directive = {
      scope: {
      },
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      link: link
    };
    return directive;
    function link(scope,elements,attrs){
      elements.attr('src','test.png');
      scope.$watch(function(){
          return attrs.test;
        },
        function(){
         if(attrs.test){
           elements.attr('src',attrs.test);
         }
        }
      );
    };
  }
})();
```

This directive is used to check whether the user is providing a path for the image else use the default one.

The js and the image are in same directory but when I am opening the html page the image is not displayed and I am getting an error like below.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)